# Make an X using drawLine

Tags: java

How can I draw an x using the drawline method?

```
g.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getX()+getWidth(), getY()+ getHeight());
```

I am assumming I would have to flip this. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
g.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getX()+getWidth(), getY()+ getHeight());
g.drawLine(getX()+getWidth(), getY(), getX(), getY()+ getHeight());
```